# How do i import a table from an html page and convert it into a pandas dataframe properly?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I need to get data from year 2012 from the following link: [wikipedia.org](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D1%258)

I used the code

```
data=pd.read_html(url,header=0,encoding = "UTF8")
data[0]
```

but it does not download the data in a proper way. The task says that requests and BeautifulSoup libraries are relevant

Comment: what error message do you get

Answer (score 0):

Try using requests-html and bs4
Here I can retrieve different tables, choose the one you need.

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 as bs4
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession


if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_url = "https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F"
    session = HTMLSession()
    my_page = session.get(my_url)

    data = pd.read_html(my_page.text, flavor="bs4", header=0)
    for item in data:
        print(item)
```